# Error: UPGRADE FAILED: values don't meet the specifications of the schema(s) in the following chart(s)

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to setup airflow using the official helm chart.

I want to set a custom values.yaml and am using the following yaml as a basis.

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/chart/values.yaml

I ran the following command.
helm upgrade --install airflow apache-airflow/airflow --namespace airflow --create-namespace --values ./values.yaml

and got the following error.
[image]
I know that the setup works fine when I don't specify the values.yaml, so am I using the wrong template or is there something else?

Comment: Any progress on the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should check if your values.yaml file has been corrupted during editing. Meaning that indentation is incorrect. If you add the values.yaml to your questions it would be easier to analyze.